# "... because sample mean gets different values from sample to sample and it is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$."

Tags: variance, mean, sample, unbiased-estimator, estimators

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87422/163242) answer by user "sevenkul" says the following:

> The sample mean $\overline{X}$ also deviates from $\mu$ with variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ because sample mean gets different values from sample to sample and it is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

I don't understand the author's justification for this. Can someone please take the time to clarify this?

Related: [Different sample covariance formulae (conventions)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/481513/163242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup here is generally that the $n$ random variables $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed, and that the mean of $X_i$ is given by $E(X_i) = \mu$ and the variance of the $X_i$ is given by $V(X_i) = \sigma^2$. The sample mean is defined by $\overline{X} = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n}{n}$. There are three claims being made here:

**Claim 1:** $\overline{X}$ is a random variable.

See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234988/regarding-sample-mean-as-a-random-variable), which goes into detail.

**Claim 2:** $\overline{X}$ has mean $\mu$.

Proof: "Mean" means the expected value, so what we're assuming is that $E(X_i) = \mu$ for all $i$. For the sample mean, we have
$$
\begin{align}
E(\overline{X}) & = E\left( \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n}{n} \right) \\
& = \frac{E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \dots + E(X_n)}{n} \text{ using linearity of expected value} \\
& = \frac{\mu + \mu + \dots + \mu}{n} \\
& = \mu
\end{align}
$$
To be clear, [linearity of expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) means that $E(aX) = aE(X)$ and $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$, properties which it has because $E$ is actually an integral, and integrals have the properties $\int aX d\mu = a \int X d\mu$ and $\int X + Y d\mu = \int X d\mu + \int Y d\mu$ so $E$ inherits these properties as well.

**Claim 3:** The variance of $\overline{X}$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Proof: "Variance" is defined as the expected squared difference between a random variable and its mean, formally as $V(X_i) = E((X_i - E(X_i))^2) = E((X_i - \mu)^2)$. You can think about this like the mean *distance* squared from $X_i$ to its mean $\mu$. Before computing $V(\overline{X})$, we need to know two important properties of variance:

1. $V(aX) = a^2 V(X)$, which is true because
   $$
   \begin{align}
   V(aX) & = E((aX - E(aX))^2) \\
   & = E((aX - aE(X))^2) \\
   & = E(a^2(X - E(X))^2) \\
   & = a^2 E((X - E(X))^2) \\
   & = a^2 V(X)
   \end{align}
   $$
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent (or even just uncorrelated), then $V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y)$ (see [the Bienaymé formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_(Bienaym%C3%A9_formula))).

We can compute the variance of $\overline{X}$ by
$$
\begin{align}
V(\overline{X}) & = V \Big( \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n}{n} \Big) \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \Big( V(X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n )\Big) \text{ using property 1} \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \Big( V(X_1) + V(X_2) + \dots + V(X_n) )\Big) \text{ using property 2} \\
& = \frac{1}{n^2} \Big(\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 + \dots + \sigma^2 \Big) \\
& = \frac{n\sigma^2}{n^2} \\
& = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Really nice, clear answer. Love that you included the relevant properties.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're sampling from a population of college students with heights distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 68, \sigma=4).$ Heights in inches.

This distribution has about 68% of heights in the interval $68\pm 4$ or $(64,72).$
Let's call heights in this interval Medium, ones below Short and ones above Tall.
If I take just one student from the population (s)he might be S, M, or T with
probabilities about 16%, 68%, and 16%, respectively. And I won't have a very
reliable estimate of $\mu.$
But if I take four students from the population, it's very unlikely they'd all be S
$(.16^9 \approx 0.0007)$ or all T. So I'm very likely to get some sort of mixture
of students, maybe 2 M's, 1 T, and 1 S. So the average height of the four $\bar X_4$
will be a better estimate of the population mean. In fact, one can show that
$\bar X_4 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=68, \sigma = 2).$

Moreover, if I sample $n=9$ students at random and find their mean height, I'll
get $\bar X_9 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=60, \sigma=4/3).$ Among nine students, I can expect a pretty good mixture of heights and a pretty good estimate of $\mu.$ [I'll be within 2in of the true average 68, about 87% of the time.]

Suppose I simulate the average heights (`a` in the R code below) of samples of size
$n = 9$ and repeat this experiment 10,000 times. Then I can make a histogram (blue bars)
of the 10,000 $\bar X_9$'s and how the distribution looks. The red curve shows the density function of
$\bar X_9 \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=60, \sigma=4/3).$ The dotted curve is for the density of the original population distribution. The vertical lines separate S, M, L heights.
[R code for the figure, in case you want it, is shown at the end.]

[image]

```
set.seed(2020)
a = replicate(10^5, mean(rnorm(9, 68, 4)))
mean(a)
[1] 68.00533  # aprx 69
sd(a)
[1] 1.331429  # aprx 3/4

hdr = "Means of 10,000 samples of 9 Heights"
hist(a, prob=T, xlim=c(56,80), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x,68,4/3), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
 curve(dnorm(x,68, 4), add=T, lty="dotted", lwd=2)
 abline(v=c(64,72))
```